# Toshiba 1TB external drive not recognised by Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: hard-disk, hardware, external-hdd

I have an external drive which I wanted to use to backup my home directory as my Ubuntu 18.04 desktop installation has been buggy lately. Initially I plugged it into the USB port of my desktop and it both was recognised and auto-mounted. For whatever reason (I was tired) I pulled it out and plugged it back in without umount. Subsequently it is now ghosting me with no sdc file popping up in /dev and no trace of it using lsusb, gparted, dmesg or a few others I tried.

I plugged it into my laptop ( also Ubuntu 18.04 ) where it was detected immediately and mounted. I partitioned it again and added a new ext4 file system before unmounting the device and trying it again on the desktop. It was still not being detected.

I have also rebooted my system several times and tried various usb ports showing that they all work. To further my confusion my desktop is recognising usb sticks.

Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks

EDIT

The output of fdisk -l which displays only my internal drives

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 232.9 GiB, 250059350016 bytes, 488397168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 001F511E-EAC4-4F52-A84C-E1DEA384BEC5

Device       Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1     2048   1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/sda2  1050624 488396799 487346176 232.4G Linux filesystem
```

The output of dmesg piped into the regex for sd

```
[    0.006822] ACPI: SSDT 0x000000008E1FEA98 003154 (v02 SaSsdt SaSsdt   00003000 INTL 20160422)
[    0.006823] ACPI: SSDT 0x000000008E201BF0 0025E1 (v02 PegSsd PegSsdt  00001000 INTL 20160422)
[    0.006831] ACPI: SSDT 0x000000008E204D98 000EDE (v02 CpuRef CpuSsdt  00003000 INTL 20160422)
[    0.902360] ahci 0000:00:17.0: flags: 64bit ncq sntf led clo only pio slum part ems deso sadm sds apst 
[    1.284781] sd 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[    1.284906] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] 488397168 512-byte logical blocks: (250 GB/233 GiB)
[    1.284913] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[    1.284914] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[    1.284926] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[    1.285012] sd 3:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[    1.285040] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] 1953525168 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/932 GiB)
[    1.285041] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] 4096-byte physical blocks
[    1.285048] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[    1.285049] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[    1.285058] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[    1.311685]  sda: sda1 sda2
[    1.312239] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] supports TCG Opal
[    1.312240] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[    1.326145] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
[    2.650657] EXT4-fs (sda2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    2.931667] EXT4-fs (sda2): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[    3.568905] EXT4-fs (sdb): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
```

Comment: In a terminal window, type `sudo journalctl  -f`, then plug in your drive.

Comment: There is no visible change to the output displayed from this command when I plug in my drive, please advise.

Comment: Try a different USB port, and try a different USB device in this port. Or, USB hardware/software might have been confused by your plugging activites - try a reboot (`sudo shutdown -r now`).

Comment: @waltinator the OP has already tried all of those. See the penultimate paragraph: "*I have also rebooted my system several times and tried various usb ports showing that they all work. To further my confusion my desktop is recognising usb sticks.*"

Comment: Can you post the output of "fdisk -l" with the drive in question plugged in and the output of "dmesg | grep sd"?  Was the drive mounted under /media/<userid>?

Comment: @CinaedSimson I have done as you asked. And the drive was indeed /media/<userid>

Comment: What size is the external USB drive with the problem? Seems odd that /dev/sdb has no Disklabel type, UUID and no filesystems. And it's a 1 TB hard drive.

Comment: And just be clear, it appears the /dev/sdb disk is your missing external hard drive. It's possible you're confusing number of disks (sdb sda) with the number of filesytems (/dev/sda1 /dev/sda2) on the /dev/sda disk you see after you login.

Comment: Hi thanks for replying. No I do not think this is correct because my external drive is currently disconnected and both these devices are still visible in /dev. sdb is a secondary drive within my computer which I have not yet used but is intended for storage in addition to the SSD sda.